# Executing two each do statements in one block in ruby

Tags: html, mysql, ruby, sinatra

Im trying to be able  to execute two `.each do` statements in one block of code for a table. I pull in the questions from one database table i pull in the answers from another and lastly I am now trying to pull in comments on the questions from a third table. this is part of what I have. It will work fine with one or the other each statements but I need to be able to pull all three tables and be able to go through each data base and have it fill out my table with how much info is in it

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" class="mytable" >

<% dataQ.each do |dataQ| %>
  <th><strong> <%=dataQ[1]%> </strong></th>     
<%end%> 

<% data.each do |data|%> 
  <% dataC.each do |dataC| %>

    <tr>
      <td><%=data[0]%></td> <td><%=data[1]%></td><td><%=data[2]%></td><td><%=data[3]%></td><td><%=data[4]%></td>
      <td><%=data[5]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[0]%></div></td>
      <td><%=data[6]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[1]%></div></td>
      <td><%=data[7]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[2]%></div></td>
      <td><%=data[8]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[3]%></div></td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and some sinatra

```
get '/display' do

  dataQ = database.execute("select * from Questions");
  data = database.execute("select * from results");
  dataC = database.execute("select * from Comments")        

  erb :display, :locals => {:data => data, :dataQ => dataQ, :dataC =>   dataC}

end
```

Comment: How is results related to Questions/Comments? What are the foreign keys used to associate the databases?

Comment: So you want one loop and iterate both arrays?

Comment: @PetrGazarov yes ,

Comment: Well i googled what you said one loop and iteriate both arrays don't know why i wasn't googling something close enough for an answer from stack to show up in Google but oh well thanks man. I used the zip method :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - your `data` and `dataC` arrays are nested, so providing they are same length, you can try this:

```
<% 0.upto(data.length - 1) do |index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=data[index][0]%></td>
    <td><%=data[index][1]%></td>
    <td><%=data[index][2]%></td>
    <td><%=data[index][3]%></td>
    <td><%=data[index][4]%></td>
    <td><%=data[index][5]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[index][0]%></div></td>
    <td><%=data[index][6]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[index][1]%></div></td>
    <td><%=data[index][7]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[index][2]%></div></td>
    <td><%=data[index][8]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[index][3]%></div></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i was able to use a zip method i found after searching for  one loop and iterate both arrays don't know why i hadn't phrased it like that but that helped thanks so much, ill try yours out and if it works ill give at least an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out after searching a better phrase thanks to a comment above :) So using the .zip method worked like a charm right away

```
<% dataQ.each do |dataQ| %>
  <th><strong> <%=dataQ[1]%> </strong></th>


<%end%> 

<% data.zip(dataC).each do |data,dataC|%> 

<tr>
  <td><%=data[0]%></td> <td><%=data[1]%></td><td><%=data[2]%></td><td><%=data[3]%></td><td><%=data[4]%></td>
  <td><%=data[5]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[0]%></div></td>
  <td><%=data[6]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[1]%></div></td>
  <td><%=data[7]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[2]%></div></td>
  <td><%=data[8]%><div class="accordion">Comment</div><div class="panel"><%=dataC[3]%></div></td>
</tr>

<%end%>
 </table>
```